# Problem in GSM interfacing with 8051 (AT89S52)

Tags: c, lcd, gsm, 8051

I have been trying to interface GSM using the code and circuit from [this](http://www.engineersgarage.com/microcontroller/8051projects/interfacing-gsm-8051-microcontroller-circuit-code) link, since 2 days. only difference is that I am using AT89S52 and SIM900A module, but I am not getting any response like OK on LCD, can anybody guide me in right direction?

Can different 8051 controller be the problem?
 I am pasting the code here:

```
// Program to Interface GSM Module with 8051 microcontroller (AT89C51) without using PC

#include<reg51.h>
#define port P1
#define dataport P2             // Data port for LCD
sbit rs = port^2;
sbit rw = port^3;
sbit en = port^4;
int count,i;
unsigned char check,str[15];
bit check_space;

void init_serial()          // Initialize serial port
{
    TMOD=0x20;          // Mode2
    TH1=0xfd;           // 9600 baud
    SCON=0x50;          // Serial mode=1 ,8-Bit data,1 Stop bit ,1 Start bit, Receiving on
    TR1=1;              // Start timer
}
void delay(unsigned int msec)       // Function for delay
{
    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<msec;i++)
        for(j=0; j<1275; j++);
}

void lcd_cmd(unsigned char item)        // Function to send command on LCD
{
    dataport = item;
    rs= 0;
    rw=0;
    en=1;
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    return;
} 

void lcd_data(unsigned char item)       // Function to display character on LCD
{
    dataport = item;
    rs= 1;
    rw=0;
    en=1;
    delay(1);
    en=0;
    return;
}

void lcd_data_string(unsigned char *str)    // Function to display string on LCD
{
    int i=0;
    while(str[i]!='\0')
    {
      lcd_data(str[i]);               
      i++;
      delay(10);                                        
    }
    return; 
}
void lcd()
{
    lcd_cmd(0x38);                      // For using 8-bit 2 row LCD 
    delay(5);                                   
    lcd_cmd(0x0F);                          // For display on cursor blinking
    delay(5);                                   
    lcd_cmd(0x80);                      // Set the cursor on first position of LCD 
    delay(5);                                   
}

void transmit_data(unsigned char str)   // Function to transmit data through serial port
{
    SBUF=str;               //Store data in SBUF
    while(TI==0);               //Wait till data transmits
    TI=0;             
}

 void receive_data()  interrupt 4   // Function to recieve data serialy from RS232 into microcontroller
 {   
    RI=0;
    str[++count]=SBUF;          //Read SBUF

 }

unsigned char byte_check()      // Function to check carraige return and new line character
{
    switch(str[0])
    {
        case 0x0a:
        {               // Return 0x00 for new line
        return 0x00;
        break ;
        }
        case 0x0d:
        {               // Return 0x01 for carriage return
        return 0x01;
        break ;
        }
        default :return 0x02 ;      // Return 0x02 for characters except new line and carriage return
    }
}

void main()
{ 
    lcd();                              // Initialize LCD
    init_serial();                          // Initialize serial port
    count=(-1);
    delay(500);
    lcd_data_string("Ready");
    delay(10);                              
    lcd_cmd(0x01);  
    IE=0x94; 
    transmit_data('A');                 // Transmit 'A' to serial port
    delay(1);
    transmit_data('T');                 // Transmit 'T' to serial port
    delay(1);
    transmit_data(0x0d);                    // Transmit carriage return to serial port
    delay(50);
    while(1)
    {
        if(count>=0)
        {
            check=byte_check();             // Check the character
            if(check!=0x00)
            {           
                if(check==0x01)
                {
                    if(check_space==1)      // Check previous character
                    {
                        lcd_data(0x20);
                        check_space=0;
                    }
                }
                else    
                {
                    lcd_data(str[0]);
                    check_space=1;
                }
            }
            count--;                   
            for(i=0;i<count;i++)            // Shift the whole array to one left
            {
                str[i]=str[i+1];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: do you see cursor on the left-most side?

Answer (score 1):

Well most of the things are same for the AT89S51 and At89S52 but yet they way header files are implemented differs hence the way the constants like **TMOD,TR1,TF1** are defined in ***reg51.h*** may be different for the AT89S52 they are defined by their hex address which may vary in these header files,hence I would adice you to use 52 header file,Lets me know if trouble still occurs.

Comment: I have used reg52.h but its still not working, and the code I have pasted is for AT89C51 not S51, I am still trying with no luck